# unknown column in 'field list' Error in phpmyadmin with php

Tags: php, sql, database, database-design, phpmyadmin

Hi I am getting this error but couldn't figure out what's wrong with it.

```
    $ID= $_SESSION['ID'];
ImageUpload($ID, 0, $IN, $Cmnt,$lll);
    $sql="INSERT INTO `Image` (`ID`, `Img_ID`,`Img_Name`,`Comment`,`Likes`) VALUES (`$ID`,`$Img_ID`,`$IN`,`$Cmnt`,`$lll`); ";
    if($conn->query($sql)==TRUE){}else{ echo "Error".$sql."<br>".$conn->error;}
    $conn->close();
```

imageupload function:

```
function ImageUpload($ID1, $Img_ID1, $Img_Name1, $Comment1,$Likes1)
{
$GLOBALS['ID']=$ID1;
$GLOBALS['Img_ID']=$Img_ID1;
$GLOBALS['Img_Name']=$Img_Name1;
$GLOBALS['Comment']=$Comment1;
$GLOBALS['Likes']=$Likes1;
}
```

Error message that I get; (Img_ID will be auto incremented)

```
INSERT INTO `Image` (`ID`, `Img_ID`,`Img_Name`,`Comment`,`Likes`) VALUES (`1`,`0`,`1631109658.jpg`,`trytrytry`,`0`); 
Unknown column '1' in 'field list'
```

What I have under the Image table : `IDx|Img_ID|Img_Name|Comment|Likes`

Comment: could you share the structure of the table?

Comment: IDx|Img_ID|Img_Name|Comment|Likes  and Img_ID is primary

Comment: btw same code structure works for another table

Comment: that is not what I asked for, but I think the problem is the ```IMG_ID``` is the set to be auto-incremented, so remove that if you want to add it yourself